# Python function which will be applied to another variable

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

For example:

```
def some_function(a):
     if a == 1:
          return x ** 2
     else:
          return x - 1000

some_function(a)(b)
```

And as result when we have `a==1`, obtain `b**2` and in all other cases `b-1000`.

Is it even possible in python, to get as return some unknown variable, which will be replaced by another?

The question is exactly about not touching `b`, it will be unreachable for function directly.

And the code which should work is `some_function(a)(b)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answer is correct in this case, but may not be suitable for what you are trying to do.

What you are trying to do is *return a function*, which Python makes extremely easy:

```
def some_function(a):
    if a == 1:
        def f(x):
            return x ** 2
    else:
        def f(x):
            return x - 1000
    return f

>>> some_function(1)(5)
25
>>> some_function(0)(1500)
500
```

Comment: Yes, this is actually what I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

This is generally referred to as *currying* or *partial* functions.  It would look like this in python

```
from functools import partial

def some_function(a, x):
    if a == 1:
        return x ** 2
    else:
        return x - 1000
```

Generally, you store the partial function

```
a = 1
func = partial(some_function, a)
func(5)
```

But you could also just use them as one liners.

```
partial(some_function, 1)(5)
partial(some_function, 0)(1500)
```

Alternatively, you could have `some_function` return a function

```
def some_function(a):
    if a == 1:
        return lambda b: b **2
    else:
        return lambda b: b - 1000
```

Using `partial` is generally the more flexible approach though.

Comment: Partial is very interesting, thank you! But the correct answer is using another def inside def.

Comment: Actually @XuMuK, the lambda is probably better here; you're only looking for simple expressions. If you needed more functionality out of the returned function (i,e statements) a `def` would be mandatory.

Comment: Thank you for lambda, it is working for simple cases, but in my case it makes errors

Comment: @XuMuK Yeah, `lambdas` can only perform a single expression (like `x ** 2`).  If you have multiple expressions or conditionals, you have to use a `def`.  Guido doesn't really like the use of `lambda`s so they've been intentionally gimped to force people to use `def`s

Answer (score 4):

Although Brian's answer works, it has code repetition and fails to leverage function closures.

Function closures mean that variables in the scope of the function definition are maintained if after the function is created, even if the variables are now out of scope.

```
def some_function(a):
    def f(x):
        if a == 1:
            return x ** 2
        else:
            return x - 1000
    return f

some_function(a)(b)

>>> some_function(1)(4)
16
>>> some_function(0)(1000)
0
```

In this instance, the variable `a` is only defined in the scope of `some_function`, but since we use it in `f(x)` it will still be available when we call the returned function later.

Comment: I'm unclear on the benefit of this approach: why do you want `a` to be available to `f()`? Or perhaps you are just making a provision for a case where `a` has to be used inside the returned function?

Comment: Yes, this way is more flexible. If `a` needs to be used in the function it can. For example, you could implement a `multiply(a)(b)` function this way without changing the structure.

Comment: @AdamVanProoyen Got it: I think "failing to leverage function closures" is more a question of what the OP needs to do than an improper implementation on my part: if the OP *needs* to use `a`, then of course it should be in the returned function. In the simple case he cites, though, it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers will work, but you may be looking for this.

```
def first_function(a):
    return a ** 2

def second_function(a):
    return a - 1000

def some_funtion(a):
    if a == 1:
        return first_function
    else:
        return second_function

print(some_function(1)(3)) #prints 9
print(some_function(0)(1500)) #prints 500
```

Comment: I am on mobile, let me know if I have made a mistake please.

Comment: it is working solution but there is no need to use three def's.